# How to get value javascript from loop for?

Tags: javascript

How to get value javascript from loop for ?

When load this code

Why not alert `2` and `3`

http://jsfiddle.net/3AaAx/41/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
    for (x = 1; x <= 5; ++x) {
      var test+x = x;
    }        
     alert(test2);
     alert(test3);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I would advise against creating dynamic variables. In this case an array would be a better choice.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var test = [];
for (x = 1; x <= 5; ++x) {
  test[x] = x;
}        
 alert(test[2]);
 alert(test[3]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wcjg6qc2/

Comment: I was surprised that worked, since the value of x at the end is 6. Today I learnt (via a very stupid question) that assignments to arrays take a copy of the literal value and not a reference. At least for ints. Of course if you tried that with objects...

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to set these values you can do :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    for (var x = 1; x <= 5; ++x) {
      window["test"+x] = x;
    }        
     alert(test2);
     alert(test3);

});
```

this is setting "global" variables with a variable name